# Converting formatted string into HTML in Java

Tags: java, html

I am publishing a message with spaces (calculated using `string.format`) and trying to show in HTML as it is. But failing to do so.

Code:

```
final String format = "|%1$-35s|%2$-20s|%3$-30s|%4$-20s|\n";
str = String.format(format,currentInputTag,currentInputVal,currentOutTag,currentOutVal)
str.replaceAll(" ", "&nbsp;");
```

String output(the way I want it to look like):

```
|Input tag                          |Value               |Output tag                    |Value               |
|FlightLegReportedUtcDatetime       |2012-07-25T01:54:00 |ns3:EstOffGroundDateTime      |2012-07-25T01:54:00 |
```

But I get:
[image]

HTML:

label|Input tag                          |Value               |Output tag                    |Value               |/label

label|FlightLegReportedUtcDatetime       |2012-07-25T01:54:00 |ns3:EstOffGroundDateTime      |2012-07-25T01:54:00 |/label

I am not sure, even though the number of spaces are correct I see the output as shown above. BTW removing <> to show the tags.

Comment: Space character widths can vary by font, sounds like you want a mono-space font.

Comment: I don't see any HTML in your sample.  If you just output the string into a browser without any HTML tags, you are going to find in very difficult to format the output the way you want.

Comment: Why not a table. Table is meant to organize data. You need such a thing

Comment: @Alfabravo I can not use table because I can not get the values individually. They come as string lines only.

Comment: Unless you use monospace fonts as @mnmnc says, it will fail depending on the data input. Also, it's possible to split str in an array

Comment: If people read my question carefully, they won't have to be so spontaneous on giving a -ve reputation to my question. Anyway I got my answer. Thanks

Comment: @MikeBrant I have provided the HTML sample in the question. I could not show the tags as they are because this application doesn't let me show the tags. (I have mentioned in the question that I am removing <> to show the tags)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit your code an wrap the output into `<pre></pre>` this will bring valid html and (if not defined different) a fixed width font.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be ideal without tedious work with counting spaces then enclose each column in table cell.

If you cannot agree to tables and want to definitely display even columns based on the space count then use monospace font and specify max column size in spaces.

Comment: I did the same thing. Thanks. +1